# Google+ integration with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, google-plus

Is there a way to post data from a ASP.NET application to Google+ account of a user. Does Google+ provide any API for the .NET platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 9-7-2011, the API has not yet been released:

http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.com/

There is, however, a platform preview for which you can sign up:

http://www.google.com/+/learnmore/platform-preview/

Here is some discussion of the issue as well as some unofficial (that is to say, they will break eventually) APIs:

http://blog.programmableweb.com/2011/07/18/the-unofficial-google-plus-api-wait-which-one/

Answer (score 2):

Since the [Google+ API](http://developers.google.com/+/) is now available, you can use the [Google APIs Client Library for .NET](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/) to access the API.